# Right binaries for my Nexus 5 (4.4.3), KRT16M or KOT49H?

Tags: android, hardware, android-source, rom, binaries

I downloaded the AOSP source code and compiled it. I used the Android 4.4.2 (KOT49H) binaries. Problem now is that I do not have any camera app at all. If I try to access it from the lock screen it says:

> Can't connect to the camera.

I suppose it *is* actually installed but not accessible from the apps view because it is not set up correctly.

My question is, should I use KRT16M or KOT49H? The Android version is 4.4.3.2.1 and on the binary [site](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers#hammerhead) it says:

> Nexus 5 (GSM/LTE) binaries for Android 4.4 (KRT16M)
>
> Nexus 5 (GSM/LTE) binaries for Android 4.4.2 (KOT49H)

Can it be that there are no drivers yet for 4.4.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4.4.3 doesn't exist. Latest version for all devices is 4.4.2

Comment: I see, thank you. How should I proceed? Checkout the 4.4.2 code?

Comment: You should definately be checking out the latest aosp 4.4.2 branch (but I don't recommend master). You should also definately be using the latest binaries.

Comment: @Paradopolis I used `repo init -b android-4.4.2_r1` and I am compiling now. I hope that works because I do not want to download 15 gb of source code again.

Comment: @SimonZettervall Some advice I have for you if you keep doing this, make a mirror of the aosp repository in /opt and just make your workspace off of the mirror. Then just keep your mirror up to date. It'll save you downloading in the long run though the first time will be harsh.